# How to proportionally fit a variable number fieldsets inside a parent div

Tags: css, html

My example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/brxpv/6/

```
<div id="window">
  <div id="parent">
    <fieldset id="fs1">
      <legend>
        fieldset 1    
      </legend>
        content...
    </fieldset>

    ... variable number of field sets ...

    <fieldset id="fsN">
      <legend>
        fieldset N 
      </legend>
        content...
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#window {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    display: table;
    background: yellow;
}
#parent {
  background: orange;  
  width: 75%;
  height: 65%;
}

input {
  display: block;
}

fieldset {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I would like all the fieldsets to be fit into the orange parent div, with equal height, regardless of how different their content is. If it's not possible to do without too much difficulty for a variable number of fieldsets - can I at least do it with a fixed number of fieldsets?

If for example there are 4 fieldsets, i'd like them to each occupy a quarter of the parent div. I **don't want the parent div to be scrollable**, but the fieldset's themselves can be scrollable.

Any idea's welcome

Comment: Do you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/brxpv/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex model

Add:

```
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

fieldset {
  flex: 0px 1 1;
}
```

## snippet

```css
#window {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    display: table;
    background: yellow;
}
#parent {
  background: orange;  
  width: 75%;
  height: 65%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  display: block;
}

fieldset {
  flex: 0px 1 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="window">
  <div id="parent">
    <fieldset id="fs1">
      <legend>
        fieldset 1    
      </legend>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fs2">
      <legend>
        fieldset 2    
      </legend>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fs3">
      <legend>
        fieldset 3    
      </legend>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fs4">
      <legend>
        fieldset 4    
      </legend>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific situation I suggest you to add `overflow-y: scroll;` to your `#parent` div like so:

```
#parent {
    background: blue;
    width: 75%;
    height: 65%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry I should have mentioned that I specifically didn't want the parent element to have a scroller, as there will be buttons below all the field sets which I want to be immediately visible (will update OP)

Comment: @Ashley Well you want to fit something that has a minimum size regarding its content into a container that has a variable size. The solution will be to hide the content which exceeds but it's not a good solution... Can you please update your question and be more specific about what you exactly want ?

Comment: If for example there are 4 fieldsets, i'd like them to each occupy a quarter of the parent div. I don't want the parent div to be scrollable, but the fieldset's themselves can be scrollable

Comment: @Ashley I think what you want to do is either impossible or bad design... Do you want the parent div to be a percentage of the size of the browser ? Or could it be a fixed height ?